# Swift Set Fix Alignment on any iphone size

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, autolayout, constraints

i know this is kinda basic question, but i really struggling on fixing my textField size width. i wanna make that my textField is regardless on what screen is always have this align 40 to the left and to the right.....so for the alignment its always 40 to the left and to the right of the screen. I dont specific the textField Widht, all i care its that no matter what the screen size is that textField will always have this 40 to the left and to the right. i watch a tutorial from udemy that shes using a stackview and view for the auto layout but i kinda hard to implement that.... i mean i dunno is theres any tips?

How do i do this in a storyboard?
im doing the autolayout from storyboard so if anyone wants to share that will be great

Thanks guys

Comment: What about the y position of the text field? Where will the text field be on the screen vertically?

Comment: well i try to implement that stackview and view, so i try to put that textField into horizontally and vertically in container, i just cant figure out how to make the textField into auto sizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the left and right margin constraints is simple. Just do:

[image]

and press "Add 2 constraints". The text field will look like this afterwards:

[image]

There are still error as you can tell by the red lines. Because...

If you want to use auto layout, you must specify unambiguously, the width, height, x position, and y position of each view.

Right now, you want your text field to be 40 points from the left side of the screen and 40 points from the right side of the screen. That makes the width and x position unambiguous. The text field itself has an intrinsic height as determined by the font size. However, you still need to tell it where on the screen it should go *vertically* - the y position. Should it go at the top of the screen? The middle? The bottom?

For example, if you want it to be 8 points from the top of the screen:

[image]

Comment: ahhh okayy thanks mate it helps me alot, cause to be honest before this i kinda still figure it out about auto layout